# HTTPS on NGINX server running wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx

I am trying to implement HTTPS on a site ased on nginx server, Now even with the below config it only opens HTTP site 
My server config for nginx server is like this

```
server {        
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.in/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.in/privkey.pem;
        server_name mydomain.in www.mydomain.in;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://$server_name$1 permanent;
}
server {


    server_name mydomain.in  www.mydomain.in;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.in.access.log rt_cache_redis;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.in.error.log;


    root /var/www/mydomain.in/htdocs;



    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    include  common/redis-php7.conf; 

    include common/wpcommon-php7.conf;
    include common/locations-php7.conf;
    include /var/www/mydomain.in/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

The server does not serve HTTPS Requests i.e even if i specifically put https in browser it still takes me back to http site. I am not able to diagnose if its nginx or wordpress which is at fault ?

> Note : the traffic is routed through cloudflare dns and certificate is
>   switch off in cloudflare so that it doesn't interfere. I am Relatively new to nginx

Comment: You have the `server` block with  `listen 443 ssl http2;` rewriting to other non-ssl `server` block so seem like it is working as you configured it.

Comment: @ShawnC. .... actually i have got this already configured by someone else in past, is there a way to route traffic to https in this config

Answer (score 0):

Well below is the basic idea.

```
server {        
  server_name mydomain.in www.mydomain.in;
  listen 80;

  location / {
    return 301 https://mydomain.in$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.in/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.in/privkey.pem;

  server_name mydomain.in  www.mydomain.in;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.in.access.log rt_cache_redis;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.in.error.log;

  root /var/www/mydomain.in/htdocs;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  include common/redis-php7.conf; 
  include common/wpcommon-php7.conf;
  include common/locations-php7.conf;
  include /var/www/mydomain.in/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

The top `server` block `listen`s on port `80` (http). It has one `location` block which does a `return` 301. `return` is preferred over rewrites in [most cases](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/). I also put it into a `location` block because you have a `letsencrypt` ssl cert which might require another `location ^~ /.well-known {` block to help handle that.

The second `server` block `listen`s on port `443` (https). It has the SSL certs and includes the information exposed previously for as the http `server` block.

This setup will handle redirecting from `http` on either `mydomain.in` or `www.mydomain.in` to `https` `mydomain.in`. On `https` both `mydomain.in` and `www.mydomain.in` will receive SSL requests.

If you want it to redirect to a primary https domain you can add another server block for the secondary(ies) like so.

```
server {        
  server_name www.mydomain.in;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.in/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.in/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    return 301 https://mydomain.in$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Of course, this means you would have to change the second `server` block to remove the secondary(ies) domain names.

Also while testing you might want to change the `301`s to `302`s so that if you misconfigure the first time that it not be stuck in the browser cache. After you get everything to a good state then change back to `301`s.